# Closable JInternalFrame closing button off-positioned

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Swing. I am creating a `JInternalFrame` that will be used as a form that will appear when certain menu item is clicked.

I set the frame as `closeable` because I want to be able to close it. I did it using Eclipse Window Builder Pro plugin, but here's the logic:

```
setClosable(true);
```

The problem is the position of the "x" closing button is off, as you can see in its right border:

[image]

Image zoomed in and when application is launched, so it can be seen more clearly:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: look closely to the right border of the button. In the image you can't see it as clearly as when I am launching the application, but it's off to the right, part of the button is missing.

Comment: This may be due to the video card you're using and how it renders the GUI. Does your computer use an NVidia graphics card?

Comment: It happens in different machines for me. Check out the new uptaded zoomed in picture where you can see the issue more clearly.

Comment: Still, just for grins, check out all the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/870472/corrupted-java-swing-window) just to see if any of the solutions help.

Comment: Just for reference: [JDK-8139392 JInternalFrame has incorrect padding - Java Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8139392)

Comment: Your code just declared a close button shall be rendered. The choice of the button and it's position all come from the JDK implementation. Have you tried different JDKs for this? Another option might be to switch the Look and Feel, which may get you around this effect ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html )